# Getting error at await in Async Task concept

Tags: c#, async-await

Folks, I am getting error at `await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ManifestStatusEntity>();`

as Cannot await something

I have seen the tutorials and implemented the code but not sure about the errors.

```
public async Task  dataRowSpy_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: Process the new request
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9667/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/psms/getmanifeststatus").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ManifestStatusEntity manifestStatusEntity =  await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ManifestStatusEntity>();
                newManifestVersion = Convert.ToInt32(manifestStatusEntity.Version);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This web API gets an Int value.
Is anything else that I need to implement?

Comment: `await client.GetAsync("api/psms/getmanifeststatus").Result` is a very bad line. change it to `await client.GetAsync("api/psms/getmanifeststatus")`.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad cannot await<HttpClent> and some TASK<>

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem in your code is further up, here:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/psms/getmanifeststatus").Result;
```

The Await keyword will **asynchronously** return the result of a task. The `.Result` property will **synchronously** return the result of a task. The problem, is that you're calling `.Result`, which returns a `HttpResponseMessage` synchronously, and then calling await on the `HttpResponseMessage` object instead of the task.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/psms/getmanifeststatus");
```

Try this.